# How to correctly set new Image in the following situation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to read the width and height of files that I get after clicking the `Browser` button:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.uploadingPanoramas.length; i++) {
  const img = new Image() // eslint-disable-line
  console.log('file', this.uploadingPanoramas[i].file)
  img.src = this.uploadingPanoramas[i].file
  console.log('img', img)
  img.onload(() => {
    console.log('width', img.width)
  })
}
```

`console.log('file')` logs:

[image]

`console.log('file')` logs: `<img src="[object File]">`

So `img.onload` doesn't actually work because I'm not getting the image apparently.

What's the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

`this.uploadingPanoramas` is an array which objects that contains the files:

```
[{
   file: File,
   progress: 0
 }, {
   file: File,
   progress: 0
}]
```

Comment: What is `uploadingPanoramas`?

Comment: @Satpal I updated the question.

Comment: seems you need `var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.uploadingPanoramas[i].file);`

Comment: @Satpal Hey, it worked can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `this.uploadingPanoramas[i].file` is [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) type you can use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to generate data URL using `readAsDataURL()` method.

> The `FileReader` object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using `File` or `Blob` objects to specify the file or data to read.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(this.uploadingPanoramas[i].file);
```